# Composing names for commands and environments

Tags: environments

I have some functionality that is implemented as a command and also as an environment.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\dkmKtlog}{ O{0.3cm} m m }
  {
    DO THIS
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{dkmKtlog}{ O{0.3cm} m }
  { DO THAT }
    { CLOSE THAT }
```

Have decided that the best way to name them is to have the commands start with the usual `\` whilst the environment version uses just the name without the `\`.  Would this be a sensible way to do things.  Or is there some standard way for all this ?

Comment: you can not do that:  a latex enviornment `foo` is implemented as the two commands `\foo` and `\endfoo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A latex environment `foo` is implemented as the two commands `\foo` and `\endfoo`.

If you try the code that you suggest then you will get an error that the environment is already defined

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dkmKtlog}{ O{0.3cm} m m }
  {
    DO THIS
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{dkmKtlog}{ O{0.3cm} m }
  { DO THAT }
    { CLOSE THAT }
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX cmd Error: Environment 'dkmKtlog' already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9     { CLOSE THAT }
                      
?
```

It is in principle possible for `\dkmKtlog` to detect that it is in the begin code of an environment and so change its behaviour, that is how for example beamer can have `\begin{frame}` and `\frame{....}` but it leads to a non standard interface and can't really be recommended.

Comment: `beamer` only does this as Till chose to deprecate rather than remove entirely `\frame{...}`. With hindsight, it would have been better if he had given a removal date ...

Comment: I suppose this is done by checking `\@currenvir`. If using the macro `\foo` right inside the body of the environment `foo`, how to detect that the command is used?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, `\@currenvir` plus a switch to say that a nested `\frame` is a 'LaTeX `\frame`'

Comment: Thusly, the sensible thing to do is to declare different names.

Comment: @Ragonese hence env form of `\raggedright`  is `\begin{flushleft}` env form of `\sloppy` is `\begin{sloppypar}`  env form of `\parbox` is `\begin{minipage}` ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need to define the environment extra:

With many macros you can do both `\macro{<argument>}` and `\begin{macro}{<argument>}...\end{macro}`, whereby `\begin{macro}{<argument>}` is just a more subtle way of calling `\macro{<argument>}` within a group/local scope.

In case `\end{macro}` shall not just `\relax` you need to define `\endmacro` "by hand".

E.g., instead of `\begingroup\bfseries...\endgroup` you can do `\begin{bfseries}...\end{bfseries}`.

However, things are different when having the environment initiate a mechanism which itself does not just process the arguments of the environment but also processes tokens from the environment's body within the local scope, as is the case, e.g., with environments like `verbatim` and with environments defined  via `\NewDocumentEnvironment` processing a `b`-type-argument.